# How to create custom repo and make it available within network through Apache on Centos7?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, repository

So i need to create custom repo & make it available within network through Apache.

Steps i did.

```
sudo yum install createrepo
sudo yum install yum-utils
```

Got tools to create repo

```
sudo mkdir –p /var/www/html/repos/ 
sudo reposync -g -l -d -m --repoid=base --newest-only --download-metadata --download_path=/var/www/html/repos/
sudo reposync -g -l -d -m --repoid=centosplus --newest-only --download-metadata --download_path=/var/www/html/repos/
sudo reposync -g -l -d -m --repoid=extras --newest-only --download-metadata --download_path=/var/www/html/repos/
sudo reposync -g -l -d -m --repoid=updates --newest-only --download-metadata --download_path=/var/www/html/repos/
```

Downloaded centos repositories to machine

```
sudo createrepo /var/www/html
```

created repo

I hope i did it right so far, but have no idea how to make it available within network through Apache.

Also, i need to put any package to it and install this package on the remote instance, and have no idea how to work around that task too.

Comment: apache just needs to be configured to allow access to /var/www/html. See the content of /etc/apache2/sites-available for some examples.

Comment: *Also, i need to put any package to it and install this package on the remote instance, and have no idea how to work around that task too.* I'm not quite sure what you mean with that, but it would seem you're now asking about administration of a *different* machine. If that's the case, please ask this as a separate question (and explain in a bit more detail, please)!